# ng-repeat does not update after changing data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**UPDATE**

1. use angular's service.
2. set $scope.items in the callback.

thanks Sylvain and Chen-Tsu Lin.

---

I am a newbie to Angular who speaks limited english. This may be a very simple question.

I am trying to display a item list when data changes. But, I don't see the list, unless I init the items before I run the code.

html code:

```
<ul ng-controller="testController">
    <li ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.description}}<li>
</ul>
```

js code:

```
function testControler() {
    var items = []
    var data = [{description: 'food'}, {description: 'fruit'}]
    setTimeout(function() { items = data }, 2000)

    $scope.items = item
}
```

Comment: You are welcome. If you are satisfied with an answer, please accept it by clicking on the check mark beside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$timeout` instead of `setTimeout`; this way you stay in the angular world. Also set `$scope.items` in the callback.

```
function testControler($timeout) {
    $scope.items = [];
    var data = [{description: 'food'}, {description: 'fruit'}]
    $timeout(function() { $scope.items = data }, 2000)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Function should execute in Angular's `$scope.apply()` method, and it will trigger `$scope.digest()` and cause data change.

Using Angular's Service like `$http`, `$timeout`, `$interval`..., it will auto  be wrapped in `$scope.apply()` and execute.

But if you use some native language feature like `XMLHttpResquest`, `setTimeout`, `setInterval`, your model change will not auto exec in `$scope.apply()`. So, data change will not happened.

#### So, use `$timeout` instead of `setTimeout`：

inject `$timeout` service inpendency

```
function testControler($timeout) {
```

change `setTimeout` to `$timeout`

```
$timeout(function() { items = data }, 2000)
```